# What problems does the Abstract Factory design pattern solve?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

The intent of the Abstract Factory design pattern is to

> "Define an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects
>   without specifying their concrete classes." [GoF]

This is a short statement of what the design pattern does (solution), 
but it isn't clear what particular design problems it solves.

Comment: **Question:** What is "GoF? Where do you have that quote from?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Gang of Four.

Answer (score 1):

I would define the 
following design, refactoring, and test problems,
but I am not sure whether this list is complete.

> #### Design Problems
>
> > **Creating Objects and Object Families**
> >
> > - How can a system support creating different families of objects
> >       so that which family to create can be selected and changed dynamically?
> > - How can a system be configured with a family of objects?
> > - And how can the whole family of objects be exchanged dynamically?
> > - How can the way objects are created (which classes are instantiated)
> >       be changed independently?
> > - How can a system be independent of how its objects are created?
> >
> > **Creating Consistent Object Families**
> >
> > - How can be ensured that a system creates objects from only one of different
> >       families at a time?
>
> #### Refactoring Problems
>
> > **Distributed Creation Code**
> >
> > - How can instantiating concrete classes throughout an application be refactored?
> > - How can creation code that is distributed across many classes be centralized?
>
> #### Testing Problems
>
> > **Unit Tests**
> >
> > - How can creating objects and object families be designd
> >       so that object creation can be mocked easily for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the long story short - if in the future a new group of objects is introduced in your current OO design, a new factory will be derived from AbstractFactory, encapsulating creation of all concrete objects related to that group. It’s that simple.

As addition is also important to say that

> “This pattern defines an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses".

In short we need a class here which will do all the common tasks and expose a virtual or abstract function.

So creating AbstractFactory will encapsulate common functionalities with an additional overridable (virtual or abstract) method and then recreate our SubFactoryA and SubFactoryB. By doing so - you'll achieve common architecture, propagate minimum/default set of practices, standards etc. Here is a [very good article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492900/From-No-Factory-to-Factory-Method) about all this.

Comment: Your addition refers to the Factory Method design pattern.  
Abstract Factory is usually implemented by applying the Factory Method pattern, but it can also be implemented differently, for example, by applying the Prototype pattern.

Comment: Or ... [Strategy](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy), after all it depends what You want and how it suites Your case.